How to remove "/app" suffix from my Catalyst application URL
I have uploaded Web app to Catalyst Web client hosting and I have mapped my custom domain to that application. But when I load my custom domain the app url is getting shown as "{custom_domain}/app".
For example if my domain name is www.example.com, the app url is getting loaded as https://www.example.com/app/. I want to remove that "/app" suffix from my application, can someone help me acheive this?

You can hide the "/app" suffix from your application URL by adding the below API rule in the Catalyst's API Gateway feature. You can find the official help documentation for API Gateway here.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:   /{path1:(.*)}
Target:        Web Client Hosting
Target URL:    /app/{path1}
The above API rule will allow the request URL to load the "Domain Homepage" without the "/app/" suffix from user perspective but in the actual scenario it loads the custom domain with the "/app/" when you make a request to your custom domain.
